# How to ref a component inside pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have this component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const authStore = useAuthStore()
</script>

<template>
  <UForm
    :ref="authStore.formRef" // this line causing a red swiggle
    :state="authStore.loginFormState"
    :schema="authStore.loginFormSchema"
    @submit="authStore.signIn"
  >
    <!-- non relevant components ommitted -->
  </UForm>
</template>
```

And a pinia store

```js
import type { Form } from '@nuxt/ui/dist/runtime/types'
import { z } from 'zod'

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', () => {
  const loginFormSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().email().min(1),
    password: z.string().min(8),
  })

  type LoginFormState = z.output<typeof loginFormSchema>
  const formState = reactive<LoginFormState>({ email: '', password: '' })
  const formRef = ref<Form<LoginFormState>>()

  const signIn = () => {
    // sign in logic

    if (error) {
     // I want to display an error to the email field.
     formRef.value?.setErrors([{ path: 'email', message: 'Invalid email or password'}])
    }
  }

  return { loginFormSchema, formState, formRef, signIn }
})
```

How can I reference its `ref` from inside my pinia store?

Comment: What error is displayed when you hover over the red squiggle?

Comment: @paddyfields There is two error when I hover over it the first is...

Comment: `The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'Partial<{ schema: any; validate: ((state: any) => Promise<FormError<string>[]>) | ((state: any) => FormError<string>[]); validateOn: FormEventType[]; }> & Omit<...> & Record<...>'`

Comment: then the second..

`Type '{ validate: (path?: string | undefined, opts?: { silent?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined) => Promise<{ email: string; password: string; }>; clear: (path?: string | undefined) => void; errors: FormError<...>[]; setErrors: (errs: FormError<...>[], path?: string | undefined) => void; getErrors: (path?: string | und...' is not assignable to type 'VNodeRef | undefined'. `

Comment: I'm using `@nuxt/ui` by the way

Comment: You generally shouldn't, business logic belongs to the stores, presentation to the components

Comment: I think it's not a use case when you separate the component logic inside a store, you could just use a composable then use the store to share the logged in user

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim That is interesting, I kinda biased towards MVC, so I thought it's the same. Business logics goes to "controllers".